# Поставить координаты изображения в jQuery maphilight

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день, отыскал вот такой плагин http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/ и нашёл пример - http://jsfiddle.net/dRz9U/162/ подскажите, а как высчитать координаты изображения для него?

Comment: @нгш, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться. Добавьте четкое описание проблемы, что вы сделали, что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlbook.ru/html/area

http://htmlbook.ru/content/karty-izobrazheniya

Почитайте об этом

Для определения координат можно использовать онлайн сервисы

http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap